# How to push commit from remotes/origin/feature/branch to remotes/gitlab/feature/branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I am new to the git and gitlab .

I need to push the commit to both gitlab and origin.But I forgot to push the commit to gitlab. I pushed it to the origin only. So my gitk --all status looks like below -

**$ gitk --all**

```
O-remotes/origin/feature/performance_test  Fixed:Fixed function 2 
|
O-feature/performance_test --remotes/gitlab/feature/performance_test Fixed:Fixed function 1
| FIXED:fixed function 0 
O TASK:added function 0
| ....
O ...
| ..
O .
```

**Query:**
How can I make sure that latest commit `Fixed:Fixed function 2` should also go to the gitlab branch and my status looks like below -

**Expectation:**

```
O-feature/performance_test  -remotes/gitlab/feature/performance_test  -remotes/origin/feature/performance_test  Fixed:Fixed function 2 
| 
.
.
```

I tried to do below command after few trials-

**git push gitlab**

```
$ git push gitlab 
Everything up-to-date
```

**git push origin**

```
To server:/gitroot/performance_test.git
 ! [rejected]        feature/performance_test -> feature/performance_test (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'tom@server:/gitroot/performance_test.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

**git pull**

```
$ git pull 
Already up to date.
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own questions after I fix this issue:

To make sure local branch feature/performance_test is not ahead of the remote branch feature/performance_test pull and merge the changes before pushing.

```
git pull origin feature/performance_test
git push origin feature/performance_test
```

or

```
git pull origin feature/performance_test
git push gitlab
```